# How much should I spend on my helmet?

Tags: frugal, regional, helmets, price, us

I'm finally going to buy a bike next month.  And a helmet.  I'm wondering how much I should budget for buying a helmet.

I'll be riding around New York City, so I want good visibility around me.  And safety is a big concern for me as well.

Comment: Related: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2207/whats-the-real-difference-between-cheap-and-expensive-helmets

Comment: The cheapest one that fits and has the features you like.  Unfortunately, it's often hard to find a helmet without tail fins these days, so it's not so much a question of price as simple availability.

Comment: Be sure to also buy gloves. You won't hit your head very often (but should still wear a helmet). But (almost) any time something goes wrong you will land on your hands. You need your hands. protect them!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Testing of helmets shows that there is little difference in impact protection. A better quality helmet, defined in this case as one that fits your head, is well ventilated, and looks good.

A well ventilated helmet prevents you from overheating while riding, especially at high speeds. A helmet that fits stays put on your head during a crash. And one that is comfortable and lightweight is less noticeable while you ride.

From a pure safety standpoint, buy a DOT/ANSI certified helmet, and you'll be fine. If you want to enjoy riding, and not mind wearing the helmet, be willing to spend more. $300 dollars is not out of line for a really high quality helmet, but that doesn't mean you need to spend that.

Find one that fits, ask your LBS to explain the ventilation differences between it and its more expensive cousins, and find one that fits in your budget. Looks good can be important, too, but that's personal and subjective.

---

> The Bicycle Helmet Safety Institute
>   submitted samples of six helmet models
>   to a leading U.S. test lab: three in
>   the $150+ range and three under $20.
>   The impact test results were virtually
>   identical. There were very few
>   differences in performance among the
>   helmets. Our conclusion: when you pay
>   more for a helmet you may get an
>   easier fit, more vents and snazzier
>   graphics. But the basic impact
>   protection of the cheap helmets we
>   tested equaled the expensive ones.
>
> The results are a testimony to the
>   effectiveness of our legally-required
>   CPSC helmet standard. Although our
>   sample was small, the testing
>   indicates that the consumer can shop
>   for a bicycle helmet in the US market
>   without undue concern about the impact
>   performance of the various models on
>   sale, whatever the price level. The
>   most important advice is to find a
>   helmet that fits you well so that it
>   will be positioned correctly when you
>   hit. [We have a page up with details of
>   the testing.](http://www.bhsi.org/briefs.htm)

---

---

Comment: Good answer - covers all the main points and backed up with a reference.

Comment: This is an OK general introduction to helmets but doesn't really answer the OP, which asks "how much *should*...?" with an implied "not too much I hope" without saying "as little as possible".

Comment: So you are answering the implied question, rather than the one asked? I told the OP to spend the most he could afford, and to find something fitting those necessities that does the job inside his budget. What exactly doesn't that cover?

Comment: I'm sorry I commented to complain, and it's good that the OP found your answer helpful.

Comment: Just fails to mention the macro economic aspect that if enough people keep buying the 150-300$ ones then the $20 will be the new $120 ones. :)

Answer (score 6):

In many countries all helmets legally sold meet a certain minimum standard. So there is no "too cheap" option, as the cheapest helmet you can buy will be considered safe enough. In this case spending more gets you a lighter, better looking (subjectively) and more comfortable helmet.

The USA also has a mandatory standard. For information about the standards and also plenty of other information and studies about the safety benefits of wearing helmets, see [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_helmet#History_of_standards)

> The American National Standards Institute (ANSI) created a standard called ANSI Z80.4 in 1984. Later, the United States Consumer Product Safety Commission (CPSC) created its own mandatory standard for all bicycle helmets sold in the United States, which took effect in March 1999.

Comment: Not in all countries, however. In many Asian countries, there is no minimum safety standard. You can usually find helmets in these places which are made to European or American standards. Just be sure to check for the certification sticker inside the helmet.

Comment: @zenbike, does a sicker mean anything in the 3rd world, or will they just be added to put up the profit of the seller?

Comment: I live in Dubai. I can't speak for everywhere, and there is always a level of trust involved with the dealer. But generally, if a product here is sold with European standards, then it is legit. I would be less concerned with third world, where the tech base is not likely up to a decent forgery, as I would in Hong Kong or Taiwan, where forgery is rampant, and the tech base is high.

Answer (score 3):

Although safety is a big concern, I don't think that a helmet per se will keep you safe. Wearing a helmet **may** make the difference between being lucky versus unlucky, **if** you're in an accident. I wear a helmet (well, a hard hat): I'm not against helmets; but the **other** things you do, e.g. choosing where and how and when to ride, would probably have a bigger effect on your safety.

I don't know that any helmet would impair visibility: it moves when your head does (and, I expect, stays up on the crown of your head instead of slipping in front of your eyes).

I may be wrong but I think that what you're buying with a more expensive helmet would be:

- looks better (if you care about the 'look')
- fits better (e.g. more ways to adjust it)
- more comfortable.

I bought a "Bern Brighton" hard hat because it was cheap and comfortable and (I hoped) more likely to at least stay on, in an accident, than others in the store which fit less well.

---

**Edit**: Someone mentioned that some helmets come with visors, which can interfere with your visibility when you're in a "heads down" position. Now I recall, I did notice some with a visor, often a detachable visor, and reflexively (note that I'm a novice buyer/user, not an expert/salesman) avoided them: I reckoned that instead of a visor I could wear sunglasses instead, if it came to that.

Comment: -1 This implies that wearing a helmet is only marginally important. Pretty much every study suggests that helmets reduce head injuries in a crash by as much as 90%, and at a minimum of 40% accounting for the difficulties in accurate data, and finding a control population for these studies. In addition, while the Bern Hard Hat helmet is appropriately safe, it doesn't fit the other categories of necessity for a good helmet, irrespective of cost.

Comment: +1 to mitigate for the unreasonable -1. Helmet wearing should not be considered obligatory. @ChrisW is correct, the helmet is not a panacea, it is a tool. It will not of itself keep you safe, but wearing one will help you in certain situations.

Comment: Lots of helmets impair visibility, due to having a visor that drops down too low.  When riding head-down on drop bars you don't want a visor in the way.

Comment: @zenbike If it's cheap, comfortable (subjective), and safe, what "other categories of necessity for a good helmet" doesn't it "fit"? I tried on every sub-$100 helmet in the store and found that this fit better (wobbled less) than every other that I tried (alternative would have been more expensive: which the salesman said were more adjustable). It is admittedly less ventilated, and doesn't look like a racing/bike helmet. Anyway, that's my data point for the OP: an amount which you can (I'm not sure about "should") spend on a helmet can be whatever you find is the cost of a Bern: e.g. $60..100.

Comment: To be clear: I would (if someone asked me) recommend wearing a helmet. Especially on the street. Especially when you're a novice. Only, don't expect that wearing a helmet will keep you safe (is enough to keep you safe): there are other, riding-in-traffic skills which you should learn and practice.

Comment: "helmets reduce head injuries in a crash by as much as 90%" another study suggest that learning to ride safely reduces crashes overall by 90%, stats can be twisted to me the needs of the twister. I wear one myself but have no intention of testing its ability to save my life. The best safety device ever invented is the human brain.

Comment: Again, suggesting that a helmet is not a vital point of safety is idiocy. Argue all you want. It's a fact.

Comment: @Moab: Agreed. It's stupid not to wear one, but that doesn't mean I want to try it out in practice. In my case there are two occasions where I'm confident I would be dead or badly hurt had I not been wearing a helmet. One of these left a 2" crease in the helmet at the base of my skull. But no one wants to crash. For what it's worth, I don't think it should be a legal requirement to wear one, because I think people have the right to be stupid, as long as they are willing to take the consequences. I just don't think we should recommend not wearing one, or imply a lack of value to wearing one.

Answer (score 2):

A more direct answer:  If you shop in a bike shop you'll probably have to shell out $50-75 for something that fits and suits your taste.  If you shop in a discount store you can likely find a serviceable helmet for $20-30, though it may not be vented as well, if that's a criterion for you.

Main criteria would be

- Fit/comfort (doesn't rattle on your head, straps can be adjusted to suit you)
- Venting (more important for longer rides and if you're apt to be really working at it)
- Durability (eg, some sort of "skin" over the styrofoam body helps)
- Visibility (depends on your riding position -- be sure to check this especially if you ride head-down on the drops)
- Not looking too dorky (for me this means no Pooh Bear decals and no tail fins)

Comment: Hint:  Place a "sanitary napkin" or "maxipad" of the self-adhesive variety in the helmet forehead region to improve the fit there and absorb sweat that otherwise would run down into your eyes.  The pads can also be used elsewhere in the helmet to keep a too-loose helmet from rattling.)

Comment: Good idea... totally getting Pooh Bear decals for my helmet

Answer (score 2):

[MIPS](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/32719/are-mips-helmets-actually-any-safer-than-standard-helmets-independent-research) may possibly make a sense, so money and choice permitting you could choose the helmet with MIPS. Some do not believe, ok. I personally also have the one with lights because I commute in the night.